# Spring framework parent object created with every child component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In my spring mvc application, i have set of repositories annotated with @Repository. i have one class which is parent to all repositories lets call it ParentRepository. ParentRepository itself is not annotated with anything. In this ParentRepository i have JdbcTemplate Object which is autowired. i am loading set of queries saved in some xml file.

Now as a standard java concept, Parent Object is created whenever a new child object is created. so it means if i have 20 ChildRepositories 20 Objects of ParentRepositry will be created? Every Object will be having different JDBCTemplate ,queries and whatever i am having in the Parent Repository class.

So is the spring doing the things in this way? what is its object creation Policy? if spring is doing the same what is the optimal way to avoid this wastage of resources? so that i could have only one jdbctemplate and one set of queries etc

Comment: You perhaps need a singleton scope for your beans.

Comment: if singleton's parent is not singleton what will happen?

Comment: on the child repositories  i am not mentioning the scope . so they will be by default singleton. so you want to say. Only one object of Parent Repository will be created?